# Property 'doRequest' does not exist on type 'any[]

Tags: typescript, next.js

Trying to create a custom hook on type script to handle errors & api
I'm getting a type error property  does not exist on type 'any[]

the hook code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';

interface params {
    method: string;
    body: object;
    url: string;
}

interface reqParam {
    message: string;
    errors: string[];
}

const useRequest = ({url, method, body}: params) => {
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);

    const doRequest: () => Promise<{} | null> = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios[method](url, body);
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            setErrors(
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                <h4>Oooops.....</h4>
                <ul className="mu-0">
                {err.response.data.errors.map((e: reqParam) => <li key={e.message}>{e.message}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
            )
        }
    };

    return [doRequest, errors];
};

export default useRequest;
```

If you require the output on how I expect the response to look like Please let me know I can give an example of that too.

The sign up file has the following code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import useRequest from "../../hooks/use-request";

const signUp = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const {doRequest, errors} = useRequest({
        url: '/api/users/signup',
        method: 'post',
        body: {
            email, password
        }
    });

    const onSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        doRequest();
    };
    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="container">
            <h1>signup</h1>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>email</label>
                <input 
                    value={email} 
                    onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                    className="form-control" 
                />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label>password</label>
                <input 
                    value={password} 
                    onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} 
                    type="password" 
                    className="form-control" 
                />
            </div>
        {errors}
            
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default signUp;
```

Any change you could help me identify the issue please? I hope the above gives enough info if any more info required please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are returning this in your hook:

```
return [doRequest, errors];
```

But you are trying to destructure as if it was a regular object:

```
const {doRequest, errors} = useRequest(...)
```

When you should be doing this instead:

```
const [doRequest, errors] = useRequest(...)
```

Comment: Omg. I do need glasses. :) good catch . thanks that worked for me.